# Use of "class Meta" in Django's admin.py

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Can someone please explain why we use nested meta class here? I understood why we use Meta class in model.py from "https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#meta-options" but I can't understand why we use it in admin.py and forms.py classes as shown below:

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import SignUp

class SignUpAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["__unicode__", "timestamp", "updated"]
    class Meta:
        model = SignUp

admin.site.register(SignUp, SignUpAdmin)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `SignUpAdmin.Meta` class will have no effect. The `ModelAdmin` does not use a `Meta` class.

You don't have to specify the model for a `ModelAdmin` class, because you specify the model when registering it. In fact, you can register the same admin class multiple times with different models.

```
admin.site.register(SignUp, SignUpAdmin)
admin.site.register(MyOtherModel, SignUpAdmin)
```

The `Meta` class for model forms has many possible options. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelforms-overriding-default-fields) for more info.